# How can I show the indicator in a VerticalScroller (android developer compose)?

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-jetpack-compose

Working on understanding android `jetpackcompose` in Android Studio 4.0 Canary.

I have a simple `jetpackcompose` setup with a `VerticalScroller` like this:

```
@Composable
fun MyScreenContent(appState: AppState = AppState())
{

    FlexColumn{


       flexible(flex = 1f){
           VerticalScroller {
             Column {
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
                CardDemo()
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

It scrolls perfectly, but I want a `scrollindicator` which shows me how far my list has scrolled, how do I turn that on, can't find any `ScrollIndicator` (i.e.) component to include.

Ref. to `RecyclerView` in a non composable setup (xml) where the `scrollindicator` is visible:

```
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/station_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/recyclerview_background_color"
                android:clipChildren="true"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:scrollbarSize="4dp"
                android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/colorPrimary"   <---
                android:scrollbars="vertical"                          <---
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:isGone="@{!hasStations}"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:context="no.rogo.projectfk303.ui.activities.MainActivity"
                tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_station" />
```

Comment: Your question is a duplicate, this question has already been asked and answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341823/jetpack-compose-scrollbars

Comment: You might be right, I asked this question 3 years and 11 months ago... I think compose was so fresh then that it wasn't properly documented.

Answer (score -1):

for jetpack compose ***desktop*** it would be:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ScrollBox(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    columnVerticalArrangement: Arrangement.Vertical = Arrangement.Top,
    columnHorizontalAlignment: Alignment.Horizontal = Alignment.Start,
    rowHorizontalArrangement: Arrangement.Horizontal = Arrangement.Start,
    rowVerticalAlignment: Alignment.Vertical = Alignment.Top,
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val horizontalScrollState = rememberScrollState(0)
    val verticalScrollState = rememberScrollState(0)

    Box(modifier) {
        Row(Modifier.horizontalScroll(horizontalScrollState), horizontalArrangement = rowHorizontalArrangement, verticalAlignment = rowVerticalAlignment) {
            Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(verticalScrollState), columnVerticalArrangement, columnHorizontalAlignment) {
                content()
            }
        }
        HorizontalScrollbar(
            adapter = rememberScrollbarAdapter(horizontalScrollState),
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd),
            style = LocalScrollbarStyle.current.copy(unhoverColor = LocalScrollbarStyle.current.hoverColor.copy(alpha = 0.35f))
        )
        VerticalScrollbar(
            adapter = rememberScrollbarAdapter(verticalScrollState),
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd),
            style = LocalScrollbarStyle.current.copy(unhoverColor = LocalScrollbarStyle.current.hoverColor.copy(alpha = 0.35f))
        )
    }
}
```

and usage:

```kotlin
    BoxWithConstraints {
        val parentHeight: Dp = with(LocalDensity.current)  { constraints.maxHeight.toDp() }

        Box(
            Modifier.background(Color.Gray)
                .sizeIn(
                    minHeight = 50.dp,
                    maxHeight = parentHeight * 0.5f
                )
        ) {
            ScrollBox {
                <your large Composables here>
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this exists anymore in beta3. Do you know the current equivalent?

Comment: it is still compiling and working with me ... what's your "problem" with it?? @A.Steenbergen

Comment: (only rememberScrollState now takes Int instead of Float)

Comment: I'm just getting an unresolved reference error for VerticalScrollbar

Comment: so my example is for jetpack compose desktop (not pure android) and VerticalScrollbar is in import androidx.compose.foundation.*
as the package indicates I thought it has to also exist with other compose variants

Comment: Yeah, seems to be desktop only. My Question was specific to Jetpack Compose for Android. Seems like there are different ways to do that.. although I can't find any.