# Jetpack Compose Scrollbars on LazyColumn and LazyRow

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Is there any way to add the scrollbars on the LazyColumn and LazyRow component? Something equivalent of these RecyclerView XML properties:

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:scrollbarSize="4dp"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

I'm using Android Jetpack Compose version 1.0.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack Compose Scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341823/jetpack-compose-scrollbars)

Comment: Are you hardcoding the height of the items? I mean do you provide fixed values for height like 50.dp?