# In compose lazy column, why there is no default option to show scrollbar?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, scrollbar, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-ui

In compose ui, lazy column or row, there is no default option to show scrollbar like in xml(android:scrollbars="vertical").

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Because the compose team have not yet implemented that feature. See the backlog on compose development (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/compose-roadmap). Or maybe you need to implement that feature, someone has implemented it. Not the smoothest scrollbar but you can tweak it (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68056586/12030603)

Comment: Looks fine, Thanks @axelbrians