# Scrollbar in BasicInputField Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to add scroll bar into BasicTextField when the text overflows the boundaries of the screen. Is there a simple way to achieve it?

I've tried to implement my own solution, but it doesn't work properly.

```
@Composable
fun Modifier.simpleVerticalScrollbar(
    state: ScrollState,
    width: Dp = 8.dp
): Modifier {
    val targetAlpha = if (state.isScrollInProgress) 1f else 0f
    val duration = if (state.isScrollInProgress) 150 else 500

    val alpha by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = targetAlpha,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = duration), label = ""
    )

    return drawWithContent {
        drawContent()

        val firstVisibleElementIndex = state.viewportSize
        val needDrawScrollbar = state.isScrollInProgress || alpha > 0.0f

        // Draw scrollbar if scrolling or if the animation is still running and lazy column has content
        if (needDrawScrollbar) {
            val elementHeight = this.size.height / state.maxValue
            val scrollbarOffsetY = firstVisibleElementIndex * elementHeight
            val scrollbarHeight = state.viewportSize * elementHeight

            drawRect(
                color = Color.Red,
                topLeft = Offset(this.size.width - width.toPx(), scrollbarOffsetY),
                size = Size(width.toPx(), scrollbarHeight),
                alpha = alpha
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a built-in way to achieve it like in Xml?

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the desired behavior? Do you mean a situation in that a text field is only partially visible on the screen so its text may overflow the screen boundaries? How should a scoll in such a partially visible text field even behave? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

To add a scrollbar to BasicTextInput there is a library https://github.com/sahruday/Carousel (credits to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69737416/6148931)

Basically you can adapt it to any view that has a scrollState